# What are "stuffed animals" called in esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests

I have neither heard nor found a good translation for these toys. Does anybody have a suggestion?

Comment: A google search for "teddy bear Esperanto" or "stuffed animals Esperanto" (without quotes) pulls up various forms of *pluŝbestoj*. How were you looking and did you find bad translations for this?

Answer (score 5):

Wells and Krause list *pluŝurso* and *pluŝurs(et)oj* in their respective entries for Teddy Bear. The more general *pluŝbesto* is also in wide use.

Examples from the Tekstaro include:

- pluŝbesto
- pluŝbesteto
- pluŝkuniklo
- pluŝ-ranoj
- pluŝurseton

Note that these are all spelled as one word with *pluŝ-* used almost as a prefix. This is not just a question of style, but comes from the rules of Esperanto word formation.

There is one stray example of *pluŝa urso* in the Tekstaro, but generally *pluŝa* is used to describe armchairs and garments - things traditionally made out of cloth. Using *pluŝ-* as a prefix indicates that this is not a living bear that just happens to be made out of cloth, but it is a kind of bear which is characterized by being made out of this material.

The author of the article in *Vikipedio* seems to prefer spelling it as two words, but a Google search for the terms show that spelling *pluŝurso* as two words is rather uncommon and spelling *pluŝbesto* as two words is almost never done.

Comment: Few living bears are made out of cloth.

Comment: Which is why "plusxa urso" is not a good choice.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that most readers can figure out that a teddy bear is not alive without needing it to be spelt teddybear.

Comment: Agreed, but "being able to figure something out" is not how good Esperanto word formation is decided.

Comment: There is no cognitive overhead in figuring out that a teddy bear isn't real.

Comment: I agree with your answer, but I have the impression that you go too much into a detail that is not asked about in the question (whether to write it as one word or as two words). Even though I think you are right about writing it in one word, what I am missing from your answer is a clarification that "pluŝbesto" is used irrespective of what fabric the toy is actually made of. So I have written my own brief answer, in which I have clarified this point.

Comment: The question is how to say "stuffed animal" and I answer "pluŝbesto". At no point to I get into what "pluŝo" is or suggest that the type of cloth makes a difference. You're correct, of course. It seems that reasonable minds can differ on which and how much detail is relevant.

Answer (score 1):

The only usual word for this is *pluŝbesto*. Even though *pluŝo* means 'plush', *pluŝbesto* is used irrespective of which fabric the toy is made of.

Answer (score 0):

They are commonly (and generically) called ***pluŝbestoj***, where *pluŝo* is plush. A teddy bear is a *pluŝa urso*, and plush items of any kind are *pluŝaĵoj*.

Felt is *felto* and terrycloth is *felpo*, so e.g. a specifically terrycloth teddy bear is a *felpa urso*. If you prefer not to specify a fabric, then you could use a term like *remburita ludilo* or *ŝtopita ludilo*. Remember that a *remburita besto* may be a taxidermied animal.

---

Tomaso tries to argue that, e.g., *papera tigro* must be spelt *papertigro* and that *porcelana hundo* must be spelt *porcelanhundo*, because otherwise people will assume that you're talking about a real tiger that is made out of paper somehow, or a living dog which is magically made out of porcelain (from the land of Oz maybe). This quibble was apparently the main motive for him to add his own reply: that there is a "rule" that an adjective must only describe, and cannot modify the nature of the noun. There is no such rule, and it would be unhelpful to have one. There is less cognitive overhead in noting that a paper tiger isn't a real tiger than in separating the parts of a unnecessary compound word.

In a comment, he then says that I "suggest" that a *pluŝurso* absolutely must be made of plush, even though the fifth word of my reply is *generically*.

Comment: Do you think that it should be consistently one word (*pluŝbesto*), consistently two words (*pluŝa besto*), or it doesn't matter? I'm thinking "consistently one word."

Comment: It's mostly a matter of style, but for offhand references the one-word form is neatest, e.g. *La korbo enhavis pluŝbestojn* rather than *pluŝajn bestojn.*

Comment: Another concern I have with this answer is that it suggests that *pluŝ-* is limited in use to stuffed animals made of specific fabric. I've never seen that in practice. All the stuffed animals I've ever been around in *Esperantujo* have been called *pluŝbestoj* with little or no thought to what kind of fabric they're made of.

Comment: To clarify - I have posted my own reply with the elements that I think are important. Specifically (1) that *pluŝ-* is the common, normal, and generally accepted way to refer to stuffed animals and teddy bears. (2) For reasons based on usage and general word formation, writing it was one word is preferable to two. (3) That *felto* and *felpo* have nothing to do with the question, and so are a distraction at best. Obviously you disagree, which is why I posted my own answer. I don't have a comment on paper tigers at the moment.

Comment: "Pluŝbesto" is used irrespective of which type of fabric the toy is actually made of. See my answer.

Comment: Alternatively, see the first sentence of my answer, where I say exactly that...